# How to get data from control in other application with Java?

Tags: java, hook

I would like to get data from other application, so i just want to read the text and save it. Or somehow to read it from other place?

I am not creator of the other application.

Comment: What kind of data do you want and how does the application look like. You can do it with XML communication or open a port between those applications.

Comment: Poker Stars Tournament Lobby. I want to get data from left table, where the prize pool is listed

Comment: Mhmmm...is it an application or website? If it is a website, you can try to get the HTML source code.

Comment: So I don't know how, cause I don't know this application. Information about this program would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do some "screenscraping" ?

Comment: PokerStars is online application, where you play poker... when you register on tournament and when tournament start, new window is opened, with title "Tournament XXXXXX", also you can open a couple of windows parented by "Tournament XXXXXX", one of them is this, i want to get this text showed in picture: 
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/qgfvI.png

Comment: Well, i was afraid of that "screenscraping"... I can't just get pure text?

Comment: you could use `Apache HttpComponents` to simmute a browser and get the text you want